# Print two remembered patterns, and only the non-alphanumeric characters between them

Tags: sed, wildcards

I'm using GNU sed 4.7 on Debian 11.

I have a file with many lines, all of which have a first string in curly brackets at the beginning of the line, a final string in `@` chars at the end of the line, and a string containing alphanumeric, punctuation and other charcaters between the aforementioned termini strings.

I want to generate output showing the first and last strings in their entirity, and **ONLY** the non-alphanum chars from the middle string, thus:

`./file` contains the following:

```
{string-no1}middle@string-no2@
{AAAAAAAAAA}1,a.B£@ZZZZZZZZZZ@
{GGGGGGGGGG}&:3m?J@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

... and I would like to see output:

```
{string-no1}@string-no2@
{AAAAAAAAAA},.£@ZZZZZZZZZZ@
{GGGGGGGGGG}&:?@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

I tried:

```bash
sed 's/\({[^}]*}\)[^a-zA-Z0-9]*\(@[^@]*@\)/\1\2/' ./file
```

...but that doesn't work, and neither does:

```bash
sed 's/\({[^}]*}\)[[:punct:]]*\(@[^@]*@\)/\1\2/' ./file`
```

...nor does:

```bash
sed '/}/,/@/ s/[a-zA-Z0-9]*//' ./file
```

I've tried finding help with grymoire, and on StackExchange too, which usually solves anything, but this one's really got me foxed. Can anybody help?

Comment: The rightmost substring in your third example line does not match the pattern which seems to assume a substring of non-`@` characters flanked by a single `@` on either side. (`@[^@]*@` does not match the entire length of `@@@@@@@@@@@@`).  It doesn't make difference for the outcome, but it is unexpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is difficult to do in `sed` (because you need to do different things - nothing, modify with `s///`, and nothing again - to three different parts of each input line) but very easy to do in `perl`.

```
$ perl -lne '($first,$middle,$last) = (/({[^}]*})([^@]*)(@.*)/);
             $middle =~ s/[[:alnum:]]+//g;
             print $first, $middle, $last' file 
{string-no1}@string-no2@
{AAAAAAAAAA},.£@ZZZZZZZZZZ@
{GGGGGGGGGG}&:?@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

First it uses a regex to extract the first, middle, and last portions of the input line into appropriately named variables.  Then it removes all alphanumeric characters from $middle.  Then it prints them.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempts do not work because the infix string (the middle bit) contains a mix of alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters.   This infix must be processed with `s/[[:alnum:]]//g`, while avoiding doing the same operation to the prefix and suffix strings.

You, therefore, need to *isolate* the infix string in a variable, or, in the case of `sed`, in the editing buffer, apply the operation that deletes alphanumeric characters to it, and then re-apply the prefix and suffix strings to the result.

With a `sed` editing script:

```
h
s/^{[^}]*}//
s/@[^@]*@$//
s/[[:alnum:]]//g
G
s/^\(.*\)\n\({[^}]*}\).*\(@[^@]*@\)$/\2\1\3/
```

Testing:

```bash
$ sed -f script file
{string-no1}@string-no2@
{AAAAAAAAAA},.£@ZZZZZZZZZZ@
{GGGGGGGGGG}&:?@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Note that the infix string on the last line is actually

```
&:?@@@@@@@@@@
```

and that the suffix is

```
@@
```

Annotated script:

```
# Remember the original line in the hold space.
h

# Remove the prefix and the suffix strings.
# The prefix is "{...}" at the start of the line.
# The suffix is "@...@" at the end of the line.
# The interior of these strings does not contain
# the respective string terminator.
s/^{[^}]*}//
s/@[^@]*@$//

# We are left with the isolated infix portion of the
# original line. Remove the alphanumerical characters
# from this. This creates the final infix string.
s/[[:alnum:]]//g

# Append the original line from the hold space to the end of
# the infix string with a newline (\n) as the delimiter.
G

# Match the modified infix, prefix, and suffix only, and
# substitute the entire buffer with these parts in the
# correct order.
s/^\(.*\)\n\({[^}]*}\).*\(@[^@]*@\)$/\2\1\3/
```

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`, you can also do:

```
perl -lne 'print /^\{.*?\}|@.*|\W/g' < your-file
```

`\W` matches characters other than alnum and underscore (only the ASCII ones by default). You can replace with `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` or `[^[:alnum:]]` if you'd like underscore to be included.

With `sed`, you could remove alnum characters between The first `}` and the first `@` after that in a loop with:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/^\([^}]*}[^@]*\)[[:alnum:]]/\1/; t1' < your-file
```

For `sed`, `[[:alnum:]]` are those classified as such in the locale and with the text decoded as per the locale's charset, while with `perl` by default, text is interpreted as if encoded in iso8859-1 and `[[:alnum:]]` only matches on the ASCII alnums (as long as you don't add the `/u` flag).

You can get a behaviour similar to `perl`s in `sed`, by fixing the locale to `C` (`LC_ALL=C sed...`), and a behaviour similar `sed`'s in `perl`, by adding the `-Mopen=locale` option, that will decode characters as per the locale charset and use Unicode properties (not the locale classification) to classify characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` equivalent, in case you want to avoid the regex:

```bash
cat file.txt
{string-no1}@string-no2@
{AAAAAAAAAA},.£@ZZZZZZZZZZ@
{GGGGGGGGGG}&:?@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

One can leave the comments when copy-pasting, as `awk` can handle them internally

```c
awk '
   BEGIN{                             # sets '}' as field separator
        FS="}"                        # splitting text into 2 fields 
   }                                  
   { 
    i=index($2,"@")                   # finds index position of '@'
    str1=$1                           # str1 = 1st field
    str2=substr($2,0,i-1)             # str2 = 2nd field until first '@' 
    str3=substr($2,i,length($2))      # str3 = 2nd field from '@' till end
    gsub(/[[:alnum:]]/,"",str2)       # replaces alphan in str2 with blanks
    print str1"}"str2 str3            # combines str1,str2,str3 and prints

}' file.txt
```

Output:

```bash
{string-no1}@string-no2@
{AAAAAAAAAA},.£@ZZZZZZZZZZ@
{GGGGGGGGGG}&:?@@@@@@@@@@@@
```